# Is there a way to check instanceof on types dynamically?

Tags: typescript

The following is pseudo-code, but I think it makes best clear what I am trying to do:

```
class C {
    public var x: number = 34;
}

var enforceType<T> = (x: T) : T {
    if (x instanceof T) {
        return x;
    } else {
        console.log(x);
        console.log(T.toString());
        throw ("wrong type!");
    }
}

enforceType<C>({});  // should raise the exception!
```

The problem is that T is not a class, but a type, so instanceof does not work, and neither does toString.  But is there a way to check at runtime whether a value is of a type I have a compile time?

Answer (score 0):

> But is there a way to check at runtime whether a value is of a type I have a compile time

No.

But

`enforceType<C>({});`

Should be a compile error!

And indeed it is :

```
class C {
    public x: number = 34;
}

function enforceType<T>(x: T) : T {
    return x;
}

enforceType<C>({});  // compile error!
```

Comment: ok, i admit to poor choice of example (:  in my actual code, i really want to do a dynamic check though, as the {} is a value received via http.

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution, but it is quite insane.  The idea is that I pass a "phantom object" to the type check function first, and at run-time, `enforceType` will deep-compare every object against that phantom:

```
var enforceType = (phantom: any) => {
    return (x: any) => {
        if (subtypeof(x, phantom)) {
            return x;
        } else {
            console.log("error", x, phantom);
            throw ("wrong type!");
        }
    }
}

var subtypeof = (_sub, _super) => {
    if (typeof _sub !== typeof _super) {
        return false;
    }

    if (typeof(_sub) === "object") {
        if (_sub === null || _super === null) {
            return true;
        }

        for (var x in _super) {
            if (!(x in _sub)) { return false; }
            if (!subtypeof(_sub[x], _super[x])) { return false; }
        }
    }

    return true;
}

class C {
    constructor(public x: number) {
        return;
    }
}

var enforceC = enforceType(new C(0));

console.log(enforceC({x: 8}));         // no exception.  good.
console.log(enforceC({z: "8"}));       // exception.  also good.
```

This is essentially a 'yes'-answer to my question, but I don't like it for two reasons:

- it's a bit convoluted (but I think there may be a way to implement enforceC as a (static) class method and provide it to an arbitrary class via a mix-in; that would improve things slightly).
- it does a deep-compare of every object at run-time.  this may be negligible for objects coming in via ajax, but it is definitely something to benchmark carefully, or preferable disabling it in production code.

Comment: (still hoping for somebody to tell me there is a much easier way!  :)